# invalid conversion from `const char*' to `char*'

Tags: c++, string, strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define SIZE 20

int main( void )
{
    int n; //number of characters to be compared
    char s1[ SIZE ], s2[ SIZE ];
    char *results_word;

    printf( "Enter two strings: " );
    gets( s1 );
    gets( s2 );
    printf( "\nEnter the number of characters to be compared: " );
    scanf( "%d", &n );
```

The problem starts here

```
    results_word = 
                 strncmp( s1, s2, n ) > 0 ? " greater than " : 
                 strncmp( s1, s2, n ) == 0 ? " equal to " : " smaller than " ;

    printf( "\n%sis%s%s", s1, results_word, s2 );

    getche();
    return 0;
}//end function main
```

So why doesn't result_word get the corresponding string ?

Comment: I think you are using a C++ compiler not C

Comment: You seem to be using Borland/Turbo C, which is not very standard complaint nor does it support modern C.  `gets()` is unsafe and has been deprecated. Use `fgets()` instead. Btw, your code seems fine.

Comment: change `char *results_word;` to `const char *results_word;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ error message you are getting says it all:

> invalid conversion from `const char*' to `char*'

You are trying to assign some constant `"<literal>"` to the non constant `results_word`.

Change

```
char *results_word;
```

to be

```
const char *results_word;
```

and it will work.

Comment: Are you assuming a C++ compiler?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: You are correct in C this would be no issue.

Comment: @Shinz6 Then tag C++. Answer differs based on what language you use.

Comment: Hasn't this been fixed in C11? String literals are now `const char*` as they always really were. Allowing `char*` for literals was a compatibility hack.

Comment: @ZanLynx You're thinking of C++11, which did remove that conversion. In C, as far as I know even in C11, string literals really have type `char []`.

Comment: gcc using `-std=c11` does not complain about `char * p = "alk";`. @ZanLynx

Comment: I guess I was wrong about C11. Disappointing. Silly too, because the result of assigning to a string literal is an access fault and crash.